# Similarity between Magento Object Manager and the Spring (Java) framework

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I am currently in the process of understanding the Magento 2 Object Manager.

Really good documentation by [Alan Storm here](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_2_object_system)

There are a lot of similarities between the Magento Object Manager and Spring (Java) core concepts. Especially -

1. Dependency Injection (Spring container, beans, DI via XML)
2. AOP (Spring does this via annotations, Magento 2 does this via XML, but both implementations are pretty similar)

Did the Magento 2 development team actively use Spring as a benchmark to re-architect Magento?

Comment: Unlikely, but to be certain if they were influenced by it you would have to ask them. These concepts are not unique to Spring.

Comment: (I tend to close the question as opinion based, but given that some of the M2 developers, including Chief Architect Alan Kent are active on the site, you might be lucky to get an official answer)

Comment: I asked because implementations are very similar. Also, someone who has Spring knowledge, can easily pick up these concepts, so can be an advantage for someone learning Magento 2. Also, if Spring is the approx. direction the Magento framework is taking, can be useful to know for someone learning Magento 2